# My server throws 504 Gateway time out when query is executed

Tags: mysql

This is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `customers` as `c` LEFT JOIN `inserted_customers` as `ic` ON `c`.`id_customer` = `ic`.`customer_id` WHERE `ic`.`customer_id` IS NULL AND `id_shop` = '3' ORDER BY `id_customer` DESC LIMIT 10
```

Both tables have currently over 70 000 rows. All ids from `customers` are in `inserted_customers` so the result from the query should be 0 rows. But it seems it tooks too long probably to join the table or something like this. How can I optimize this and does it need optimization or the problem is somewhere else ? Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to change some of configuration in your database because it is configure in a short period of time when executing a query, example in my xampp `max_execution_time=10000`

Comment: So I have to check the max_execution_time. Got it

Comment: Yeah and also this `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;`

Comment: You can check the execution plan of your query by adding `EXPLAIN` in the beginning and run it. Copy and paste the result of the `EXPLAIN` into your question. My guess is that you probably don't have any indexes on those tables or particularly on `ic.customer_id` and `id_shop` columns.